# user id with which beeline executes the commands

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop2, hive-metastore

I am trying to understand what is the relationship between the various id's when we run a Hive query. 
I am considering the following scenario, which is suggested for real clusters.

`ClientMachine` ---connects / ssh--> `GatewayNode` (say user1, serverA) ---> `HiveServer2( ServerB` ---> `Driver` --> `Remote MetaData Service (serverC)` --> `MySql (serverD)`

Actual data is stored in `HDFS`, which can have its own set of users.

Now, my doubt is, we have different users for each layer, for example, MySQL DB, HDFS, HiveServer2 etc; so if I login to GatewayNode as user1 and if that userid isn't in either HDFS or MySql  , how does this situation work?

Can anyone help understand this in easy to follow?

Answer (score 2):

HDFS/Hive should be configured to share user accounts. And ideally, not have the same user/password information as the backend database. E.g. You configure the hive-site with the metastore user & password, but that's not a Hadoop user for Hive to user.

This can be enabled by external systems via Pluggable Authentication Modules (PAM), or KERBEROS (Active Directory, for example), or LDAP. The latter two being recommended.

By default, Hive and Hadoop have no authentication, and usernames are taken literally as strings.

For more information, see [Hive wiki on Authentication](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Setting+Up+HiveServer2#SettingUpHiveServer2-Authentication/SecurityConfiguration)

If you want a secure Hadoop cluster, you need to setup a kerberized environment, setup Java keystores over each JVM environment, and ideally use tools such as Apache Ranger or Sentry to lock down access and audit your cluster

Answer (score 1):

Just attempting to provide an easy to follow flow.

When going through the component/node flow that you have in mind:

`ClientMachine ---connects / ssh--> GatewayNode (say user1, serverA) ---> HiveServer2( ServerB ---> Driver --> Remote MetaData Service (serverC) --> MySql (serverD)`

Note that, we need to consider what is the identity that needs to be authenticated with the service provider for making its services available. With this, let's start from Right to Left:

1. MySQL: This hosts the metastore data. This service provider is OK as long as a client(here, the metastore service) has authenticated with it and has opened an authenticated session with an agreed/configured MySQL DB user and password. It doesn't need end user(i.e. user1) visibility.
2. Remote Metadata Service: As implied, provides Metadata service to hiveserver2 primarily, but can be used by other services such as spark, impala etc. This is actually a thrift based server so the usual mode of authentication is Kerberos based. So, this seems to have the end user visibility as far as authentication is concerned. Also refer this [metastore security guide](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/cdh_sg_hive_metastore_security.html) on user impersonation.
3. HiveServer2 : Detailed security configuration guide from Cloudera [here](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/cdh_sg_hiveserver2_security.html#concept_mbt_rgx_nm). This is supposed to autheticate the end user (user1) using any of the methods explained in the link and in the links provided in other answers to your question.

But of specific interest is the section on [HiveServer2 Impersonation](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/cdh_sg_hiveserver2_security.html#concept_vxf_pgx_nm)

> Impersonation support in HiveServer2 allows users to execute queries and access HDFS files as the connected user rather than the super user who started the HiveServer2 daemon. Impersonation allows admins to enforce an access policy at the file level using HDFS file and directory permissions.